# Can I use xargs as part of a directory path?

Tags: bash, unix, xargs, cp

I have this directory structure:

```
% ls /tmp/source_dir/
aa-aa/  bb-bb/  cc-cc/  morejunk/  somejunk/

% ls /tmp/dest_dir
aa-aa/  bb-bb/  blah/  blahblah/
```

For every directory in dest_dir matching ??-??, I want to copy a corresponding file "goodfile" from the source_dir.  I have tried the following to no avail:

```
% cd /tmp/dest_dir

/tmp/dest_dir% \ls -d ??-?? | xargs cp /tmp/source_dir/{}/goodfile {}
cp: cannot stat `/tmp/source_dir/{}/goodfile': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `{}': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory `aa-aa'

/tmp/dest_dir% \ls -d ??-?? | xargs bash -c "cp /tmp/source_dir/{$0}/goodfile {$0}"
cp: cannot stat `/tmp/source_dir/{/bin/bash}/goodfile': No such file or directory
```

Surely there's a way to do this without writing a separate script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `xargs` should work:

```
cd /tmp/dest_dir

\ls -d ??-?? | xargs -I{} cp /tmp/source_dir/{}/goodfile {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution but without xargs

```
find . -iname "??-??" -exec cp goodfile "{}"  \;
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be executed from /tmp/dest_dir?  If so, you'd have to specify source_dir in the path somewhere, right?

Comment: Yep. You can first cd to /tmp/dest_dir or just put the enteri path on command like find /folder/to/find -iname "??-??" -exec cp /folder/goodfile "{}"  \;

Comment: Ah, ok, just had to tweak it a bit: find . -name "??-??" -exec cp /tmp/source_dir/{}/goodfile {} \;